# Calculate p value for two large table

Tags: python, r, t-test

I have two table with size `199*170` and `199*160` of two groups which contains a set of drugs on two different groups, since the sample size is large, how do i calculate p value

**Table 1**

```r
    DrugA   DrugB   DrugC
Sample1 0.0188195099    18.8376134835   25.8114015207
Sample2 0.0112548226    6.0024840676    36.5992030979
Sample3 0.0125878532    40.5633875857   16.2631488459
```

**Table 2**

```r
    DrugA   DrugB   DrugC
Sample4 0.0179567469    20.6071029295   18.6102131088
Sample5 0.0208501509    12.6901628267   76.9699214129
Sample6 0.0130571829    14.1503594412   22.7963816355
```

As these table are large, how can I find out which drugs are significant? how do I calculate p value for these.

Comment: Can you explain more? I see two tables with (Possibly) N rows and 3 columns. Where 200x170 comes from? Even if that's the case, these tables are not large for modern hardware and Pandas.

Comment: @MSH, Thank you. These 3 column is example data to represent the actual tables. Yes these are may not be large, but could you please share a tool/package which can be used to calculate.  Thank you

Comment: What test do you want to do, i.e. what do you mean by "significant"?

Comment: @user2554330, t test maybe? i want to calculate p value for all drug in both groups. Thank you

Comment: But you have a different number of drugs, 170 vs 160.

Comment: @user2554330, No i have same number drugs (199) and differnt number of samples (170 and 160)

Comment: `scipy` is what you are looking for. See: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html

Comment: What exactly is your null hypothesis? What does it mean to say "a drug is significant"? Leading to larger/smaller values on average than the average of the other drugs? What is the relation between the two groups? Do you want separate tests for them? What is the actual meaning of a "sample"? Proper statistics needs more background information than what is given here. If I were consultant here, I'd want to know how exactly the data were obtained and what the values mean.

Comment: The usual convention in describing matrices is ROWS x COLUMNS, so you should have said your tables are 170 x 199 and 160 x 199 if you're displaying samples as rows. If you want to do t tests on them, you can do so one column at a time.  You do need to worry about the things @ChristianHennig said: that only makes sense under certain assumptions.  You also need to worry about interpretation of p-values if you do 199 tests on the same samples.

Comment: @ChristianHennig, Thank you for your input. Here are some information, hope it helps understanding the question. The two groups are cancer patients with different regulation of a pathway (1. Up regulated 2. Downregulated). And both the group have same set of drugs. The values are predictions of their drug response obtained using r package called OncoPredict. My question was since r package runs the prediction a set of drugs, how do i eliminate drugs which show low respose (or statically  less significant). Thank you for your time.

Comment: @user2554330, Sorry for the confusion regarding the convention. I have added reponse to questions pointed out by ChristianHennig. Please go though and let me know if more information is required.

Comment: @Luffy Please add information to the question rather than giving it just in comments. Comments will not be read by many. I still don't understand whether a "sample" is a single patient. In that case there could be dependence between the observations in a sample, which makes the whole thing far more complicated.  Also I suspect that by "significant" you mean in comparison to "no treatment", which can't be assessed as apparently there were several treatments for everyone.

Comment: If it makes sense to think of the two groups of patients as random samples from their populations, then a t-test might make sense, but watch out for different variances between the two groups.  You still need to worry about the multiple testing issue.  If you are doing 199 tests when there are no differences at all between the groups in any test, you'd expect about 10 of them to have "significant" p-values (i.e. p < 0.05).  Using a Bonferroni correction says to only declare significance if p < 0.05/199, i.e. p < 0.00025.  There are other less extreme corrections.